# Why I am getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, attributeerror, findall

I am getting an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'".
I googled why the error occurred but couldn't find an answer.
Does anyone know why the error comes out?

```
 for page in range(pages):
    base_url = "https://kr.indeed.com/jobs"
    final_url = f"{base_url}?q={keyword}&start={page*10}"
    
    print("Requesting", final_url)
    
    browser.get(final_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
    job_list = soup.find("ul", class_="jobsearch-ResultsList")
    jobs = job_list.find_all("li", recursive=False)
```

I want to fix the error and know what the error exactly about.

Comment: Like [the docs say](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=find#find): if `find()` can’t find anything, it returns `None`.

Comment: Either print out or inspect job_list. It will be None, as I am guessing that B BeautifulSoup isn't finding any ul with that class